# How to create a circle with text inside

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a personal website following the code that I got from [here](https://html5up.net/aerial). I have no background in HTML and I'm actually only using it to create this website. I was trying to create a circle that is similar to one of the icon's circles in the link above (same radius, colors, location on page, etc), but with the text "CV" inside (since I couldn't find a CV icon logo). Is there a way to do it?
I tried various modifications of the line:

```
<li><a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank" class="icon solid fa-camera"><span

class="label">CV</span></a></li>
```

But since I have no HTML background I'm just trying random things that don't make sense or work (like removing "fa-camera"), or stuff along those lines

Update:
I'm attaching the `index.html` file code from the website's template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Aerial by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aerial by HTML5 UP</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="bg"></div>
            <div id="overlay"></div>
            <div id="main">

                <!-- Header -->
                    <header id="header">
                        <h1>Adam Jensen</h1>
                        <p>Security Chief &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; Cyborg &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; Never asked for this</p>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-facebook-f"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon solid fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </header>

                <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer">
                        <span class="copyright">&copy; Untitled. Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</span>
                    </footer>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() { document.body.classList.remove('is-preload'); }
            window.ontouchmove = function() { return false; }
            window.onorientationchange = function() { document.body.scrollTop = 0; }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update 2:
Changed the `index.html` file code to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Aerial by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aerial by HTML5 UP</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript> 
    <style>.cv:before {contet:"CV";}</style>

    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="bg"></div>
            <div id="overlay"></div>
            <div id="main">

                <!-- Header -->
                    <header id="header">
                        <h1>Adam Jensen</h1>
                        <p>Security Chief &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; Cyborg &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; Never asked for this</p>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#" class="icon brands cv"> <span class="label">Curriculum Vitae</span> </a> </li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-facebook-f"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon brands fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon solid fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </header>

                <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer">
                        <span class="copyright">&copy; Untitled. Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</span>
                    </footer>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() { document.body.classList.remove('is-preload'); }
            window.ontouchmove = function() { return false; }
            window.onorientationchange = function() { document.body.scrollTop = 0; }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My last answer was a cheap option... Here's how to do what you actually want:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="icon brands cv">
        <span class="label">Curriculum Vitae</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Style:

```
.cv:before {
    content:"CV";
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate all the help! So similar to before, do I copy the first cell to the main.css file? What do I do with the Style? Do I keep the same HTML code as before?

Comment: @MaxK As you can see, I changed a class from e.g. "fa-twitter" to "cv". The style can go in any css file that will be loaded.

Comment: Okay, so I copied the Style to the bottom of the main.css file. Replaced the fa-twitter to cv, but the circle disappeared. I think I may have copied the Style to a bad place? I don't think it's loading

Comment: @MaxK The class of the <a> wrapping around the <span> has to have this class: "icon brands cv". It should work then.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the <a>. I copied the exact HTML code you wrote and replaced it with the twitter line of code. I also copied the Style to the bottom of the main.css file. But still no circle

Comment: @MaxK So, you did it just like your modifications but with the class "cv". Do you see the "CV" on the button (without border as you said)?

Comment: Actually I don't see "CV" at all or a circle using this code. In the previous solution you proposed the CV and circle appeared, but here there is just a blank spot where the circle should be

Comment: @MaxK then please try to insert my css in your html file with a <style> tag. Like this: <style>.cv:before {contet:"CV";}</style> in the Documents <head>

Comment: Okay, added it in the head section, but still no circle : /

Comment: @MaxK could you please update your question with your new stuff, so I can see it?

Comment: Yes. Just updated - see update 2. Note that in my update the style is not aligned for some reason, but it is in my html code.

Comment: @MaxK Is the index file on a server?

Comment: Nope, it's on my local machine

Comment: @MaxK Very weird... I did the same on the website you linked to and it works fine...

Comment: Weird. Did you modify the main.css file? Should I delete the previous things I added to it (from your solution before)? Can you add the entire index.html file the way you wrote it?

Comment: @MaxK Of course, the problem was the worst I could think of: spelling mistake... Just correct "contet" in the style to "content"... I'm sorry...

Comment: Hahaha brilliant! No worries! Thank you sooooo much for all the help!!! I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: @MaxK No problem. But I'm still sorry for wasting so much time for such a simple solution...

Comment: Pfff no worries at all. I've been working on this for like 3 days now, so a few more minutes to figure out a small issue is really not a big deal. The fact that I have no idea what's HTML or css are didn't make it easier on you either

Answer (score 2):

Tried to replicate it:

```css
body {
  background: rgb(115, 201, 230);
  margin: 20px;
}
.radio {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  border: solid 1px white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: white;
  transition: .3s;
}
  .radio:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Button</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="radio cv">CV</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks amazing!! Could you tell me where to put the code? Apologies in advance, HTML is completely foreign and I'm not sure how to take the code and put it in a logical place. See my update- I attached the index.html file's code from the website's template

Comment: You'd need to copy the css into the main.css file or include it in a <style> tag. Then all you'd need to is paste <button class="radio cv">CV</button> into where you wanted it (I imagine as one of the <li> elements)

Comment: @David_2002 Which one is the css? the top? Or both? Do I just copy it to any line in the main.css file?

Comment: @MaxK the top one. The one below is HTML.

Comment: @ZerobyteHD Okay so I copied it into the main.css file (at the bottom of it), and I tried to copy what @David_2002 said into the line: `<li><a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank" class="icon solid fa-camera"><span

class="label">CV</span></a></li>`, but so far I managed to get the "CV" text to appear, but I can't see the circle and the text appear on another icon

Comment: @MaxK You could put the CSS-declarations in *any* CSS file, that will be loaded. ".radio" stands for an element with the class 'radio'. That means that the declarations above apply to elements such as <button class='radio'></button>.

Comment: @ZerobyteHD Gotcha! That makes a lot of sense. I'm still trying to play around with the line: `<li><a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank" class="icon solid fa-camera"><span  class="label">CV</span></a></li> `. I changed to to `<li><a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank" button class="radio cv">CV</button><span
                                class="label"></span></a></li>` - It probably doesn't make any sense (since it doesn't really work that way), but I'm not sure how to copy it to the right place

Comment: You're nearly there you need to close the <a> tag and then open the <button> tag. This should work: <li><a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank"><button class="radio cv">CV</button></a></li>

Comment: @David_2002 Woohoo! So close! Okay, this almost works- I got the circle and the CV text inside, but it's much larger than the other circles and overlap one of them. How would I change it to be the same radius/size? Is that the css part?

Comment: @MaxK Just posted a new answer with a *much* better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small < div > and then with css give the rounded corner property until it's completely round

Comment: I appreciate the comment! But as I have no background in HTML I don't really know what you just said. What's < div > ? css? Can you direct me to an example or something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
<div class="circle"> My Text </div>
```

```
.circle{
  border-radius: 50%; 
  border-style:solid; 
  behavior: url(PIE.htc); 
  width: 110px; 
  height: 110px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Keep the width and height the same to keep it a perfect circle.

Comment: If you can't edit the style sheet you can move it in-line e.g <div class="circle" style="border-radius: 50%;  border-style:solid; behavior: url(PIE.htc); width: 110px; height: 110px;  overflow: hidden;  display: flex;align-items: center;  justify-content: center;"> My Text </div>